# Добавление заголовков в метод CONNECT

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, proxy

Всем привет! У меня имеется клиент и прокси сервер на С#. Клиент для соединения с сайтом через прокси сервер использует метод CONNECT. Подскажите есть ли возможность в метод CONNECT добавить дополнительно какой-нибудь заголовок?
Для организации клиента использую HttpWebRequest. С помощью клиента я отправляю Connect запрос на прокси сервер. На прокси я вижу заголовки, как на картинке (сверху консоль прокси-сервера). Потом рукопожатие, открытие тоннеля и получение html страницы на консоль клиента (внизу). Конкретнее мой вопрос можно поставить так, могу ли я на клиенте либо на прокси сервере добавить заголовки к запросу CONNECT, не только User-agent, host и proxy-connection?

[image]

Comment: Мало вводных. Нужно больше информации. Что за клиент Вы используете и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

> Для организации клиента использую HttpWebRequest

Для добавления заголовков у HttpWebRequest есть свойство [Headers](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers?view=netcore-2.1#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_Headers).

```
request.Headers["X-My-Custom-Header"] = "the-value";
```

Или

```
request.Headers.Add("X-My-Custom-Header", "the-value");
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб CONNECT запрос содержал заголовки, которые я добавлю в незашифрованном виде. Заголовки добавленные через свойство Headers, пойдут уже в зашифрованном виде.

Comment: Если Вы используете HTTPS, это невозможно. При его использовании шифруется весь трафик между узлами.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать клиент, так чтобы незашифрованный CONNECT запрос  от клиента с добавленным моим заголовком доходил до прокси сервера.

Comment: Тогда используйте обычный HTTP.

Comment: Может быть есть другие библиотеки,  которые позволяют к методу Connect добавить дополнительные заголовки?

Comment: Дело не в библиотеках, а в протоколе. Любая библиотека работает по соответствующим протоколам. Всегда!